# How to apply all updates automatically for fresh install of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I had to reinstall Windows 7 on my laptop. How can I tell Windows Update to completely update my laptop without asking the user nor waiting to restart. I want it to run overnight and get everything installed and done by morning.

Comment: closests thing to doing that would be to start the update manually. the use of deployment practices, http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5842 as you can see right there, it is not a good way to do it for a single computer.  Another method would be to start with a slipstreamed SP1 then go from there, another learning process that would go well beyond simple.

Comment: Very close related to http://serverfault.com/questions/320750/best-way-to-fully-update-a-new-installed-windows/352225#352225

Answer (score 8):

Schedule the following command to be run on startup:

- wuauclt /detectnow

And go into Windows Udpate and change the settings to say "Download and install updates automatically", then you should be able to start Windows Update manually and go away. After the update is completed it'll reboot, after the restart it'll go look for more updates.

Answer (score 4):

[This utility can make a DVD](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) or USB flash drive to run an unattended installation of all Windows updates, reboots automatically and continues updates until all of them are installed.

Do lots of reading before making the DVD.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use [WuInstall](http://wuinstall.com/). It is a command line tool and allows you to search for Windows Updates, download and install them and to specify the reboot behavior. In your case, a simple wuinstall /install should do what you want, however the reboots are still an issue which you might have to do manually.

Comment: it has a lot of options, but didn't seem to work that great

Answer (score 0):

***Perform instructions below at your own risk***:
To automate windows update these instructions may or may not work for your system however it appears to work to an extent for Windows 7 as these instructions were tested on Windows 7.

***MUST READ: 1. If the step below does not work verify then you are most likely part of a domain and your security policy may not allow you to perform steps below! 2. UAC prompts were also disabled for the duration of the windows updates so the batch files can run without interruption; be careful to restore this to default when done***

***Caution this step will make your computer less secure, immediately remove this after your computer is completely up to date. Set a reminder for 24 hours later if need be***:

***1.***
First you will have to make sure your computer automatically logs into a user. You can do this by clicking start menu, type "netplwiz", press enter or open the wizard, under the users tab, select your username,  and un-check "require password", type your password, close this window.

***2.***
Create 3 batch files to start the automated process. (Open notepad paste each code into a separate notepad and perform a save as corresponding_file_name.bat)

One. Save as: any_name.bat then copy this batch file to your startup folder for the user you made auto login. (Click start > All Programs > Startup)

```
start "" c:\autoupdate1.bat
exit
```

Two. Save as: autoupdate1.bat then copy this to C:\ drive

```
wuauclt /detectnow
wuauclt /updatenow
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" > nul && shutdown -r -t 0
start "" c:\autoupdate2.bat
exit
```

Three. Save as: autoupdate2.bat then copy this to C:\ drive

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 61 > nul
start "" c:\autoupdate1.bat
exit
```

Restart or open the batch file in the startup folder and watch the magic begin!

***3.***
When it is completely done updating just delete the batch files from the startup folder & c:\ drive

***Once again follow these instructions at your own risk as it can create an endless loop if you do not know how to stop this process by removing it from the startup folder or going into windows under safe-mode to remove the batch files***

Final notes: If you run into issues running the batch files chances are you may have to look up how to disable UAC prompts for your Windows version